# How to send HTTP GET request to Firebase Realtime DB on POSTMAN?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, httprequest, postman

I have an android messaging app and I save all data to firebase realtime db. I want to get user data on c#.

First, I try to send GET method on POSTMAN with this url https://MY_PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com/users/USER_ID

and returned data is :

[image: answer]

I just want to get some JSON that includes my user's data. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the HTML button and change it to JSON.

Comment: I get this answer when changed it to JSON :
Unexpected '<'

Answer (score 0):

just append .json at the end like this:

https://MY_PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com/users/**USER_ID.json**